# HTML5 video tag used with mp4 but no play on galaxy s4 or iphone

Tags: html5-video

hello guys i am trying to get our companies videos on our website using html5 video tag rather than embedding a youtube video and it seems to work fine on a desktop but will not play on my samsung galaxy s4 or iphone.

i have only provided an mp4 in the code as various converters i have tried fail to convert them to ogg or webm (which im guessing is needed for mobiles?)

here is a sample of the code

```
        <video controls poster="images/sparta-street-safe-graphic.jpg">
          <source src="security-videos/private-security-firms.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <h2 class="white">Sparta on BBC news </h2>
```

can I just ask is there a problem with my code or is it as simple as me just providing another format if so which format?

and if providing another format is the answer does anyone know why the various converters refuse to convert these particular videos to ogg or webm  (i have flv files taken driectly from youtube and mp4 files that they were converted too)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. But there is a problem with browsers preferring MIME types one over the other.
Order the video src elements in the following manner. It may work sometimes.

> 1.video/webm
>
> 2.video/ogv or ogg
>
> 3.video/mp4

I ran a single src webm video [big buck bunny](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html) on a nexus 4 successfully. But couldn't do it with multiple src videos. In Desktop Firefox, it preferred OGV over WEBM and MP4, but still did not play it. In safari, it did not play any `<video>` with multiple `src`, but played all with `<embed>` tag. So, you see, it doesn't work all the times.

You may run into problems where the `<video>` element doesn't show up, care for giving some `height` and `width` attribute with values.

Answer (score 0):

convert your video to m4v format and it will works fine.